# cloning private repo using ruby-git

Tags: ruby, git, github

I'm using [ruby-git](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git) to programmatically perform some operations git repos hosted on GitHub.

Everything works fine when I do it on public repos however, I'm not able to clone private repos even if I have created an ssh key on the machine when the code runs and added the public one on GitHub. To make sure the key is properly setup I have cloned the repo directly from the terminal and the repo was successfully cloned. The key has also been added to the ssh-agent and `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set.
So, I think the issue is related to how I use the ruby-git gem.

Here my (simple) code

`@repo = Git.clone("git@github.com:#{repo_full_name}.git", path)`

And here, if it may be helpful teh error

```
 Git::GitExecuteError: git clone '--' 'git@github.com:USER/REPO.git' '/var/www/repo-root/USER/REPO' 2>&1:Cloning into '/var/www/repo-root/USER/REPO'... Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read
```

Am I missing anything here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your Git env config pointing at your ssh key path?

```
Git.configure do |config|
    # If you want to use a custom git binary
    config.binary_path = '/git/bin/path'

    # If you need to use a custom SSH script
    config.git_ssh = '/path/to/ssh/script'
end
```

Comment: No. Do you mean something like ```config.git_ssh = '/users/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'```?

Comment: I'd give that a shot, or without the id_rsa.pub, that's all I can think of right now, hope it helps!